# iOS 15 - Notification sounds are not playing for foreground notifications

Tags: ios, usernotifications, ios15, unusernotification

What is the right way to play a tone associated with notification in iOS 15 without displaying banner or list?

When handling notifications in foreground, both local and push, notification sounds are not playing if `UNNotificationPresentationOptions` is only `sound`. If additional options like `banner` or `list` is added along with `sound` then notification tone plays.

When app is in background, all options of notification presentation are working properly.

I know `alert` option is depreciated from iOS 15. Is using `sound` as the only presentation option, no longer valid?

Below is the snippet

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler 
completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
     
     completionHandler(.sound) //not working
     //completionHandler([.banner, .sound]) //works
     //completionHandler([.list, .sound]) //works
     
 }
```

**Update:** Apple confirmed that this was a bug and it is now fixed in iOS 16 beta 2. No solution for iOS 15 though.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277080/before-ios-15-i-was-able-to-send-sound-only-local-notification-now-i-have-to-s) (also no good answer yet)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
You would need to set the completion handler like this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {

    case .active:
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            completionHandler([.sound, .list])
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            completionHandler([.sound])
        }
    default:
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            completionHandler([.banner, .sound])
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
        }
    }
}
```

Now the in-app notifications come with sound and with my custom banner.

`.list` will add the notification on the Notification Center as well, which I find very useful, in case the user is using the app and missed some notifications.

Comment: The question clearly asks how to make `[.sound]` work in iOS 15 without using list or banner options.

Comment: @return0 Well, it seems that it is not working on iOS 15 just with `[.sound]`. You would need to choose either `.banner` or `.list`. The second option won't show any visual representation of an incoming notification while the app is in `foreground` state. You can show a custom in-app popup if you want.